# Is the order of execution of resolved Awaitables well-defined in Hack?

Tags: async-await, hacklang

The example below fires off 1000 async `usleep` calls separated by 100μs, then blocks the main thread before `join`ing:

```
<?hh
$awaitable = HH\Asio\v((new Vector(range(1, 1000)))->map((int $wait_time) ==> {
    return async {
        await HH\Asio\usleep($wait_time*100);
        echo $wait_time."\n";
    };
}));
usleep(1000000);
HH\Asio\join($awaitable);
```

[The result in stdout (3v4l)](https://3v4l.org/Avt1l) indicates the order that control returned to the `async` scopes.

The program consistently spits out a monotonically-decreasing sequence from 1000 to 1, suggesting that the finished `Awaitables` are pushed onto a stack and popped once the thread is freed in **LIFO order**. Is this ordering real, and can I rely on it?

Answer (score 1):

This is deliberately not specified, and may change in the future -- and has already changed before. The only thing about async functions you can rely on is that after you `await` them then they have executed and returned their result.

(This also means, for example, that you should not rely on what happens when you invoke an async function but don't immediately `await` on it.)

Answer (score 0):

If you rely in the exact ordering of `Awaitables` being collected or executed, you are probably doing something wrong.

`Awaitables` are supposed to be used for IO.

Could you explain a bit more why do you need exact ordering?

Comment: Originally, I thought that I could use consistent ordering in an Observer implementation for a merging operation (actually, I was hoping for FIFO), but after thinking further yesterday, consistent ordering alone is not strong enough.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, this ordering *is real, as [ready await handles are explicitly processed in LIFO order](https://github.com/facebook/hhvm/commit/2782370d6888e8623acf3f6ad8aa3442e313dc7d). However, as @pablo-alcubilla writes, it shouldn't be relied on until it enters the HHVM spec, if ever.

Comment: It is in the code for performance reasons, but the language spec says nothing about that.

Comment: Do not rely on this -- it is deliberately not specified, and can (and has!) changed before.